# Unblocking the ask question feature

Tags: support

I searched and found at last that my ask question feature is not working due to repetitive questions etc. I got my mistake, after that I still continued my contributions through answering, but will i never get the chance to ask question in coming future, because i need help many time also now I got it what I should not do so 
what should I do now start with another account or wait?

Comment: I assume you have deleted some questions? Deleted questions are a part of the question ban. You shouldnt delete questions unless it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: yup i deleted few questions also, because they were particularly related to me and was for no help to others, and didn't got answer here so i deleted, coz don't know the rule than

Comment: @JoshMein by way how to decide it is absolutely necessary, coz u make me confused again, just after i thought now i know some ABC of stack-overflow

Comment: You just need to remember that you are currently banned. If you manage to get out of the ban, and delete more questions, you will likely get banned again. Just be careful not to delete too much.

Comment: As for getting unbanned, hopefully a moderator will come around and undelete some questions for you.

Comment: @JoshMein: It's highly likely that the deletion status of a question does not affect question bans.  In any case, mods don't have much ability to affect this outcome (by design).

Answer (score 2):

You may delete your question but it will not be removed from stackexchange.  [Users with 10K+ can still view your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

It is a community site, so someone will be benefited from yours.   Better reopen your question and fix it with your updates.  If still it is a valid question, community will vote it and so you will get back the privilege of asking questions.

**Refer:** [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/233367)

> ***Do not delete your posts***. As explained above, deleted questions (if less than 30 days old when deleted) do still count towards the
>   question ban. ***Deleting your posts does not help to lift the ban. Only
>   fixing does***! Under some conditions you can see a list of your own
>   deleted questions and answers.

Comment: what kind of contributation they are needed I have the same issue in my other(Stack over flow) account i was blocked at 122 bounty & now i have more then 500 also flaged so many question & edited as well still i am not unblocking how they are judge that now i should unblock?

Comment: @123456789 answering or flagging posts is not considered for [unblocking the ban](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217684/233367).  Its fully depends on the question that you've asked.  I would suggest you to take a look at **How do I avoid getting a question ban?** section under [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/233367)